# Generate filename without white space in c

Tags: c

The code below generate file name based on: destination directory, radio station name and current time:

```
static int start_recording(const gchar *destination, const char* station, const char* time)
{
    Recording* recording;
    char *filename;

    filename = g_strdup_printf(_("%s/%s_%s"), 
        destination, 
        station,
        time);

    recording = recording_start(filename);
    g_free(filename);
    if (!recording)
        return -1;

    recording->station = g_strdup(station);

    record_status_window(recording);

    run_status_window(recording);

    return 1;
}
```

output example:

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Europa FM_07042012-111705.ogg
```

Problem:

Same station name may contain white space in title:

```
Europa FM
Paprika Radio
Radio France Internationale
    ...........................
Rock FM
```

I want to help me to remove whitespace from generated filename
output to become so:

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EuropaFM_07042012-111705.ogg
```

(a more complex requirement would to eliminate all illegal char. from filename)

Thank you.

UPDATE

If write this:

```
static int start_recording(const gchar *destination, const char* station, const char* time)
{
    Recording* recording;
    char *filename;

    char* remove_whitespace(station)
    {
        char* result = malloc(strlen(station)+1);
        char* i;
        int temp = 0;
        for( i = station; *i; ++i)
            if(*i != ' ')
            {
                result[temp] = (*i);
                ++temp;
            }
        result[temp] = '\0';
        return result;
    }

    filename = g_strdup_printf(_("%s/%s_%s"), 
        destination, 
        remove_whitespace(station),
        time);
    recording = recording_start(filename);
    g_free(filename);
    if (!recording)
        return -1;

    recording->station = g_strdup(station);
    tray_icon_items_set_sensible(FALSE);

    record_status_window(recording);

    run_status_window(recording);

    return 1;
}
```

Get this warning:

warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: Why do you consider a space character as an illegal character for a file's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void remove_spaces (uint8_t*        str_trimmed,
                    const uint8_t*  str_untrimmed)
{
  size_t length = strlen(str_untrimmed) + 1;
  size_t i;

  for(i=0; i<length; i++)
  {
    if( !isspace(str_untrimmed[i]) )
    {
      *str_trimmed = str_untrimmed[i];
      str_trimmed++;
    }
  }
}
```

Removes spaces, new lines, tabs, carriage return etc.
Note that this also copies the null termination character.

Answer (score 1):

if you can modify the names in place you can use something like this:

```
char *remove_whitespace(char *str)
{
   char *p;

   for (p = str; *p; p++) {
      if (*p == ' ') {
         *p = '_';
      }
   }
}
```

if not, just malloc another string the same size, copy the original string into it and free it after use.

Comment: This should be named `replace_whitespace` and also deal with other isspace() characters.

Comment: This is probably reasonable, but worth mentioning that both "a b" and "a_b" will result in "a_b", so there's a potential for distinct inputs to collide after mapping.  Separately, "just malloc another string the same size, copy the original string into it" - strdup() does that nicely in one call.